# Enabling WL.JSONStore in Worklight project from Eclipse?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I have a project in eclipse and using IBM Worklight but on my js file where i have placed this code

```
WL.JSONStore.init(JSONStoreCollections).then(
            function(res) {
                WL.Logger.info('Response is :', res);
                WL.JSONStore.get(chekVodafoneData).findAll()
```

I am getting a red mark under WL.JSON and it show JSONStore is not enabled ? I have already refered [How to enable WL.JSONStore in Worklight project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17144301/how-to-enable-wl-jsonstore-in-worklight-project), but it didn't helped much ?

Comment: Check for latest version of Worklight.

Comment: Rita, Where in your project did you place it? Did you look at how it is done in the sample project?

Comment: Pawan: Its 6.1.0.xxx.

Comment: I am trying out Sample Form based Authentication and tried using JSONStore just for learning purpose.

Comment: Ohh My BAD, i did not saw your latest comment but i have posted a fix. just try this once.

Comment: On refering How to enable WL.JSONStore in Worklight project? i came to know about version issue but i have latest one i guess. I will try asked fix and let you know. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The reason you are getting the error that JSONStore is not enabled is because it is an "optional feature" and must be enabled in the application-descriptor.xml file. Open this file in Eclipse, and in the "Design" tab simply right click "Optional Features" and select JSONStore. This should remove any errors stating that JSONStore is not enabled.

For implementation details of a JSONStore, see: [JSONStore Infocenter (6.1)](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.help.doc%2Fwl_home.html)